# Gurobi: Optimize a quadratic non PSD

Tags: mathematical-optimization, psd, gurobi

Will Gurobi optimize a quadratic problem where the objective function
is NOT positive definite?  Our constraints are linear--in fact, they are
box constraints.  This is a known NP-complete problem, as per Vavasis,
Nonlinear Complexity: Optimization Issues, Oxford University Press.

We know that Gurobi will not optimize a quadratic programming problem
with quadratic constraints, except under special conditions.  However, we
have not seen a specific statement that it can or cannot handle
a quadratic objective function.

Answer (score 0):

Gurobi is designed to handle problems with objective functions that are linear or

- convex quadratic functions for minimization problems
- concave quadratic functions for maximization problems

In addition, it can handle quadratic constraints where the feasible region is convex or a [second order cone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-order_cone_programming)

You haven't mentioned the type of problem that you are tackling, but if you want to use Gurobi to solve it, the best approach is probably to use its mixed-integer linear optimizer, or use a decomposition method.